# Credit Card Payment on a HTTPS / SSL site via VPN: is my data safe?

Tags: vpn, proxy, transaction-log, vpn-client, safety

Since the [closest Q & A I have found](https://serverfault.com/questions/432855/how-to-protect-my-credit-card-transaction-data-from-hackers-proxy-server) about this topic doesn't quite match the focus I have in mind, I felt that a more precise question could be a helpful point of reference for me and many other users in my same situation.

I need to access a specific content on a web site that isn't be available from my country, and make a payment: *so I think **I necessarely need to use** a proxy or **VPN** service*.

[The payment page is a SSL-secured webpage on a HTTPS protocol](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfKGKjyQWvjxZmzH7Z9gLNIrghzech-b/view?usp=sharing).

Like many of us, I've heard and read about reliability and hazard issues concerning VPN services (especially those free ones) so many times that I am *simply worried* that my **credit card data** could be **stolen**, **intercepted** or simply **exposed**.

So the question simply is: even if I run into the worst and most criminal VPN service, will my data be **safe as long as the payment page is HTTPS** and / or **SSL** webpage, right? Or there may be some issues anyway?

and that's all, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your worry is the VPN service then they can't decrypt the SSL traffic from the website. They could only decrypt their VPN traffic. So think of your packet now like a gift wrapped 2 times. First the browser wraps your traffic in the SSL encryption then your VPN client wraps its encryption over the SSL.

So if your VPN service is looking at your traffic and using the key to decrypt it it will be left with the SSL encryption which it doesn't have the key for and can't decrypt.

Comment: thanks very much. But, when you say "if your worry is the VPN service" this means that I should have other worries :)? Thanks anyway: I can't upvote yet but I will mark it as problem-solver

Comment: What about a simple MiTM? THE SSL could be improperly issued by any trusted CA in the users browser.